# Can I upper-bound uncertainties of $B$ in an eigenstate of $A$ using an appropriate norm of $[A,B]$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

There are times when I would really like a "reverse" uncertainty principle to hold, allowing me to **upper-bound** certain uncertainties in terms of properties of commutators. I'll try to explain a setting where I'm tempted such an upper-bound could make sense: I'll have two Hermitian operators, $A$ and $B$, where $[A,B]$ is quite "small".

In particular, I have in mind that the sum of the moduli-squared eigenvalues of the commutator, $Tr[ [A,B]^\dagger [A,B]]$, is **not** infinite, ruling out the case of $A,B=x,p$. I'll also restrict to $Tr[A^\dagger A]$ and $Tr[B^\dagger B]$ also finite, and I personally am interested in the case where $Tr[ [A,B]^\dagger [A,B]] \ll Tr[A^\dagger A]Tr[B^\dagger B]$.

I'd then want to consider a case where I'm in a **unique** eigenstate of $A$ with eigenvalue $a$, $A|a\rangle = a |a\rangle$. Can I upper-bound  the quantity
$$\sigma^2_B \equiv \langle a| B^2 | a \rangle - \langle a|B|a\rangle^2 < \text{some function of some appropriate norm of the commutator, } ||[A,B]||\text{?} $$

One could imagine this for instance being useful in finite Hilbert spaces, like in spin chains.

I would really like this "reverse" uncertainty principle to be true! I unfortunately expect the answer is no, and that there's a quick counterexample that I'm missing.

---

A quick numerical check of $2$ by $2$ GUE matrices shows the following:
[image]

Though there's a rough trend of shrinking uncertainty when the Hilbert-Schmidt norm shrinks, it's tempting that there might not be a strict upper-bound in terms of $Tr[ [A,B]^\dagger [A,B]]$ alone -- such an upper-bound would have to pass above all the points, and it would be quite steep near 0.

Comment: If the operators are Hermitian, then $tr\{A^{\dagger}A\}=tr\{A^2\}$ and $[A,B]^{\dagger}=-[A,B]$.

Comment: @flippiefanus I agree. It's a personal choice, but I will choose to write the square of the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of the matrix $M$ as $Tr[M^\dagger M]$ (since that way of writing it is always true, even if it can be written differently).

Comment: It is assumed you have explored your point with 2x2 matrices?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks, I randomly-sampled 2x2 GUE matrices and I've added in a plot of uncertainties against the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of the commutator. While there is a rough trend, I think the graph doesn't bode well for any putative strict bounds (at least not any bound that is linear in the Hilbert-Schmidt norm).